# Integral of the form $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax}e^{-x^{4}}dx$

Tags: improper-integrals, exponential-function, mathematical-modeling, hypergeometric-function

I'm searching a closed form for the integral of the form :

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax}e^{-x^\frac{\alpha}{2}}dx
$$

especially for $\alpha=8$

After several attempts, I find that the general form can be written on the basis of hypergeometric functions. what do you think ?

Comment: I see you wrote down "Especially for $\alpha=8$". Which one would you like us to write an answer for?
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax}e^{-x^{4}}dx$$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax}e^{-x^\frac{\alpha}{2}}dx$$

Comment: expand $ e^{-x^4})$ into a power series and uses the integral of the gamma function $ \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{n}exp(-ax) = \Gamma (n+1)/a^{n+1} $

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I need a closed form for the general case no matter the value of alpha ,

Comment: I'm curious about the context where this somewhat strange integral occurred. Do you mind telling us?

Comment: @yassinehmamouche: a hypergeometric series is considered as a closed form? You cannot get something better than that for a generic $\alpha$.

Comment: The case $\alpha=6$ is related with Airy functions, for instance.

Comment: @jack D'Aurizio : you are right , for alpha =6 the closed form is related to airy functions , more precisely scorer function Hi

Comment: @mickep : i found this stranger integral when searching to calculate the formula of coverage probability on the case of Rayleigh channel and interferers (digital communications)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio : I need an optimised formula under the hypergeometric functions

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio are you found some thing for alpha = 8 ?